# Azure/Xamarin Mobile App Hangs at SyncContext.InitializeAsync

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

So, I had a working xamarin forms app that used azure mobile services. I upgraded the server side to use mobile app service and upgraded the nugets in my client to use the latest and greatest client codes.

I manually updated my test/ios simulator sqlite db to use the proper column names for the system properties since they dropped the double underscore prefix.

When I finally got it all built and tried to run in the ios 6/8.3 simulator it ran fine until it hit the InitializeAsync method. It doesn't throw (its in a try catch) and I let it run for a long time and it just sits there.

I then tried to change the db name so it would make it from scratch, which it did but still just hung. So I then tried to simplify it to a single table and took out my delegating handler so it was as basic as I could get it and it still just hangs.

Has anyone else had this problem? I am at a complete loss because I don't get an error. Not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Edit, code added:

```
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(_localDatabaseName);

store.DefineTable<Profile>();
try
{
    await _mobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I also tried with ConfigureAwait(false) as suggested but it made no difference.
I set breakpoints in the catch and the code that immediately follows this block but they are never hit.

Comment: can you try adding ConfigureAwait(false) like so: InitializeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) and try again ?

Comment: @jmichas - Can you post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I poked around a bit more and found some info on deadlocked threads answered by Stephen Cleary, the guru of async/await.
It turned me onto looking upstream. The call into my azure init code looked like this:

```
var azureService = Container.Get<IAzureService>();
azureService.InitializeAzync().Wait();
```

Which was in the constructor of the calling component.
So, I changed it to this:

```
try
{
    Task.Run(() => azureService.InitializeAsync()).Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

And the SyncContext.InitializeAsync() call worked fine and continued on.

So, I don't really know the answer for this, I guess the internals of the new azure client do something differently than the old code since using Wait() was how I did it before and never had a problem. But there was some sort of threading deadlock. Very odd and took days to get past, now I have to fix the next deadlock I hit. If Stephen is out there and can offer some clarification that would be great.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the .Wait() call, because you can end up accessing the sync context before it is initialized. You should instead use await.

Comment: @lindydonna-msft Yeah, unfortunately that code is in the constructor of my App.cs class so it can't be awaited. I also tried to move it to an async void Init() method but it had a strange effect in the UI leaving a white screen on iOS instead of the splash screen like it does if it blocks in the constructor before the main page is set.

Comment: can be used like this too:

try
{
    Task.Run(async () => await azureService.InitializeAsync());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue - changing to a Task.Run and ConfigureAwait(false) did fix it.

Very odd thing is the same code worked fine with Mobile Services, but broke when we upgraded to Mobile App Services.